# Plotting a function u(x,y) at different 'x' locations in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I have a NumPy matrix of the form **u(x,y)** which represents the velocity of the fluid in the x-direction. For now, let us consider that **u**, **x**, and **y** as follows:

```
nx,ny = 101,101 # no_of_points
x = np.linspace(0,20,nx) # X domain span
y = np.linspace(0,3,ny) # Y domain span

u = np.random.randn(nx,ny)
```

I wanted to plot this matrix **u** at different x-location, like plotting **u[0,:]** (which represents **u(x,y)** at **x=0** and at all **y**), **u(10,:)** (which represents **u(x,y)** at **x=2** and at all **y**), **u(20,:)** (which represents **u(x,y)** at **x=4** and at all **y**)  and so on like the one shown in the figure below.

[image: Velocity at different x-locations]

How can I achieve this using matplotlib? For now, I was able to develop a contour plot using:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.contourf(X, Y, u, levels=50, cmap='jet') 
plt.colorbar()
```

which looks something like the image below

[image: Backward step flow]

But, I am not interested in contour plots (or the quiver or streamline plots), rather I am looking for the one I have described above (same as the figure I have attached)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dummy example is a bit confusing as it is fully random.

Let's use another one that looks a bit more similar to what you want to achieve:

```
y = np.linspace(0,3,20)
x = np.sin(y)
t = np.linspace(0,10,5).reshape(-1,1)
X = x+t
```

Now we can loop over the time to plot the series:

```
ax = plt.subplot()
for my_x in X:
    ax.plot(my_x,y, marker='o')
```

[image: time series plot matplotlib]

Alternatively, you can take advantage of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) by converting to [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X.T, index=y)
df.index.name = 'y'
df.columns.name = 'time'
df.plot()
```

[image: pandas plot]